# angular-ui replace'?' with '#' on redirect from facebook oauth

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, angular-ui-router

I'm implementing facebook ouath login in angularjs without SDK.

Everything works as expected except one thing.

When user click on login button, which redirects to facebook login page, after successfull login, facebook fires redirect_uri URL, and user is again in the app.

Problem is, that ui-router (probably) replaces '?' with '#' in path, so

`http://localhost/fbauth?access_token=xxx&code=yyy`
becomes
`http://localhost/fbauth#access_token=xxx&code=yyy`

Because of that, i cannot use `$stateParams` to get object with query params.

Suprisingly, when I manually enter in browser or click link to 
`http://localhost/fbauth?access_token=xxx&code=yyy`
 everything works properly, and ui-router does not replace '?' with '#'.

I guess, that it's related to redirection scenario itself.

Can someone point me what I do wrong, or how to change ui-router behaviour in this case?

This is the state, that handles fb redirect:

```
.state('fbauth', {
  url: '/fbauth?access_token&code&expires_in',
  templateUrl: 'static/public/public.html',
  controller: 'publicCtrl'
});
```

PS ui-router is set to work in html5 mode with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: This is correct behavior for the UI Router. It is very specific about the kind of parameters it will take and wants to alter your URL or re-write it. We could discuss the advantages of redirecting to a different url... But the more common practice is to use a Login Dialog and Call back method rather than a URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this resolve function to your state, which will replace a hash url with the query string url:

```
resolve: {
    'urlFix': ['$location', function($location){
        $location.url($location.url().replace("#","?"));
     }]
}
```

- So a url of `/fbauth#access_token=123456&code=abcde&expires_in=99999999` would be redirected automatically
- Becoming `/fbauth?access_token=123456&code=abcde&expires_in=99999999`
- `$stateParams` would be populated correctly.
- The value would be `{access_token: "123456", code: "abcde", expires_in: "99999999"}`
- `$location.url()` doesn't update if the location matches already, so the state won't redirect when there is no `#` present.

### Full example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FBAUTH</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <base href="/">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <script>
        angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
            .controller('publicCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
                // $stateParams should be correctly set (even for hash route)
                console.log($stateParams);
            }])
            .config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider', function($locationProvider, $stateProvider){
                $stateProvider
                    .state("fbauth",
                    {
                        url: '/fbauth?access_token&code&expires_in',
                        templateUrl: 'fbauth.html',
                        controller: 'publicCtrl',
                        resolve: {
                            'urlFix': ['$location', function($location){
                                $location.url($location.url().replace("#","?"));
                            }]
                        }
                    });

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank You very much. This works perfectly. Enjoy Your bounty :).

Comment: @Jarema Thanks, glad it helped. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Scott, what about if I have code like this:

$stateProvider
      .state('access_token',
        url: '/access_token=:access_token'
        controller: ($location, AccessToken) ->
          hash = $location.path().substr(1)
          AccessToken.setTokenFromString(hash)
          $location.path('/')
          $location.replace()
        templateUrl: ''

How do I edit this to fix that same problem?

Comment: @JCC You add the code from the resolve section `resolve: {
                            'urlFix': ['$location', function($location){
                                $location.url($location.url().replace("#","?"));
                            }]
                        }`

Answer (score 1):

I would not prefer passing query parameters(using ? mark) in client side routing. Instead you can use route/state params as follows:

```
http://localhost/#/fbauth/access_token/:access_token/code/:code
```

and you can access these values using `$stateParams`. e.g. (`$stateParams.access_token`)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, as I wrote in my question, I cannot dictate the format of URL, as it's redirection from facebook ouath.

Comment: Can you check `$location.search()['access_token'];`, is this works