# Angular UI-Router - How do I parse hash params?

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, angular-ui-router

How do I get the values after the '#' sign in the url?

I am manually building a login flow with Facebook, and it redirects me to a url that looks like this:

```
http://example.com/redirect#access_token=1234567890&expires_in=12345
```

My route in UI Router looks like this:

```
  .state('redirect', {
    url     : '/redirect?token',
    templateUrl : '/html/redirect.html'
  })
```

Right now I can call `$location.hash()` and get a string to parse into values.  But this approach feels hacky.  Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to get the hash params out of this URL?

**EDIT:** To be clear, Facebook is adding that '#' into the url. I have no idea why they aren't just using a '?' because getting query params is simple.

Comment: Try $location.search().

Comment: That does not appear to work after a '#' like it works after a '?'

Comment: Please have a look at the answer of this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257293/angular-ui-replace-with-on-redirect-from-facebook-oauth). He's using `resolve` to change the location `#` to a `?`. That should work.

Comment: @AWolf Thanks!  I think Milos suggested that below, and I will likely accept that as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this config , this will expose this parameters to $stateParams (if they are set). Dont user $location.search() if its natively supported by ui-router .

```
/redirect?token&expires_in
```

Then inside state (can be inside resolve)

```
.state('facebookCallback',{
  controller : 'ctrl',
  resolve :
   url : function($location) {
    return $location.url().replace("#","?")
   }
  }
 });
```

Comment: I have tried that.  It does not appear to work after a '#.'  It seems hash params are different from query params.

Comment: you have wrong redirect url it should be `http://example.com/#/redirect?access_token=1234567890&expires_in=12345`

Comment: I'm not making the redirect.  Facebook is the one that puts a '#' into the url.  I wish access_token were passed as a query param.  No Idea why it isn't.

Comment: No, I am using HTML5 mode with no hash in my original url

Comment: so i would direct facebook to special url example.com/facebook , so he will push example.com/facebook#params, then you can try rewrite this url to index.html/redirect?params

Comment: i just read FB docs, it seems stupid that they are redirecting with hashbang ... but anyways , this is case when you need to hack it with $location service.  but i would try `$location.url().replace("#","?")` , so ui-router will parse it as params (with my above setup). And you dont have to deal with hacky parsing.

Comment: Thanks!  I think that is an ok answer, but I am going to let the question sit for a little while before accepting that answer - to see if there is maybe a more elegant solution.

Comment: I am interested too , i will be soon implementing facebook oauth so its interesting question.